# Use of dot inside brackets is breaking the swig template

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

Use of Dot inside curly brackets is breaking the rendering of swig template. I am not sure if its a bug.

I have the code like this some where in between html text for a article:

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <span>new Promise (function  (resolve, reject) {...}  );</span>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Using dots inside brackets `{...}` is breaking the rendering. Why? When I remove it was working fine but I had to track down the issue.

Comment: I would guess `{}` means something in Swig, and `...` is an invalid Swig expression. You probably need to escape the `{}` somehow. Seeing that the documentation seems to be archived, it's hard to tell…

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `{` and `}` are reserved characters in Swig.

Swig will evaluate everything inside those characters, so it is trying to evaluate `...`, which isn't a valid Swig expression.

You need to replace replace those characters with HTML entities to prevent Swig from evaluating them.

```
<pre>
    <code>
        <span>new Promise (function  (resolve, reject) &#123;...&#125;  );</span>
    </code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Is there any filter in swig that automatically does this?

Comment: Or I have roll out my own?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to get a Swig filter for this, because you will somehow need to apply the filter without Swig parsing the `{...}` as a Swig expression. You'll need to manually replace `{` with `&#123;` and `}` with `&#125;`